# Python rounding final answer from a formula

Tags: python, syntax, formula, rounding

Currently have a formula that outputs a number, with the round() function rounding the answer to a whole number. How can I get 3 decimal places in my answers.

Odd request, but is there a way for it to round down always, even if 5 should round it up?

```
orderSize = round((availableBalance * 15 * 1 * (1-(0.00075 * 2)))/lastPrice)
```

Comment: You want to round to three decimal places? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this `orderSize = round(((availableBalance * 15 * 1 * (1-(0.00075 * 2)))/lastPrice),3)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use string formatting to achieve this.

```
price = '{:.3f}'.format(orderSize)
```